# Centering Two Divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

In my document I have a header and a nav tab just below it with several li inside a ul. In my masthead, I have a .png logo. Now I would like to center the nav and its elements while creating two gutters in the document but more importantly I want the logo in the masthead to be positioned above the nav where the first li element begins.

In the terrible illustration below you can see what I am trying to achieve:

```
    |.PNG |  

    | li  |  li  |  li  |  li  |
```

So far the list elements are centering, but I cannot left center the .png as shown above.

Thanks in advance for the help. \:D/

**EDIT:**

The HTML

```
<header><img src="whatever.png"</header>
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/">7</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
header {margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;}
.nav {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Please post your html/css code. Either here or on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, please post your HTML/CSS code **here** (and if you'd like to show a demo, _also_ use jsFiddle.) @BillyMoat: Do not solely rely on jsFiddle when posting code.

Comment: For one thing, `margin: auto 0` is backwards.  Use `margin: 0 auto` instead.

Comment: @Sparky, yes I saw that. I was lazy when I wrote this which is why that happened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the header and nav the same width and fix the margins.

**CSS**

```
header,
nav
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <img src="logo.png">
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Will this work if I set the nav and header elements to width: 100%; ?

Comment: Ofcourse, but then you don't need to set any `margin: 0 auto;` since it is used to center the content in the window, but with `width: 100%` it won't need to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. That was most satisfactory :)